# Check when was Amazon S3 bucket last accessed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to get a list of buckets that are not used over a period of 1 year is there anyway to see the last read of the objects of s3 bucket

I tried using cli but it didnt work

Comment: Do you have data access logging enabled with CloudTrail and CloudWatch? If you have this set up, visiting the CloudTrail logs should work.

Here's more info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/LogAPICall.html

Comment: @AliAvci no cloudtrail is not enabled

Comment: Unfortunately you can only check the last modified time of an object directly with S3, there is no last accessed time. Another way is CloudWatch metrics for S3 which can log request metrics at object level. But like CloudTrail, this is not enabled by default and you have to configure it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cloudwatch-monitoring.html